# Laravel URL rewrite cascade or forward to route for same pattern URLs

Tags: php, laravel-4, url-routing, laravel-routing

I am facing a problem with URLs having same structure but serving different resources. 
Consider example Below:

`GET /mumbai/mobiles
GET /travel/best-getaways-from-delhi`

now in my routes.php I have Rule definition as below:

`Route::get('/{city}/{category}', array(
    'as'    => 'citySearch',
    'uses'  => 'SearchController@doSearch'
));`

`Route::get('/{category}/{pageSlug}', array(
    'as'    => 'pageUrl',
    'uses'  => 'pageController@pageView'
));`

Obviously, If I request `/travel/best-getaways-from-delhi` it'll match first rule and I won't be able to serve the content. My Logic here is either I can write a filter/or in controller a code which will lookup all cities and if there is no city ( i.e. travel is no city) it'll  forward my requests to second rule (`pageUrl`).
How can I do that? or can anyone suggest me a better approach. Thanks

Comment: I am facing same issue but solving it... no luck. please tell me if you got any answer, tnx

Comment: @MKGarwa, `Route::get('/{k1}/{k2}', function ($k1, $k2) {
// check if $k1 is a city. if its a city then perform search
// if $k1 is not city then check for blog post URL. 
})`

Answer (score 0):

I would add a prefix to the URL to differentiate. For example have the links like `/city/mumbai/mobiles` and `/page/travel/best-getaways-from-delhi`

Comment: no adding a keyword is not an option. If I could then there was no need to post a question